# Can't add data into a database field when using variables

Tags: php, mysql

I have a table called "utilizatori" (it means "users" in English) with 5 fields, the fifth one being called "cartea_favorita" and is empty for all rows (i.e. users) from that table. I'm trying to add some text into the fifth field for a particular row (i.e. user).

The following code does not add anything in the database. If I replace in the `mysql_query` function `$titlu_carte` with a text string and `$nume` with a text string as well, then it works, but when I use the variables it doesn't.

The funny thing is that when I `echo` `$titlu_carte` or `$nume` in the page I see the values being displayed correctly, but for some reason it doesn't work when added in that query. Any solutions?

```
<?php
    $lista_carti = mysql_query("SELECT `titlu` FROM `carti` ORDER BY `titlu` ASC");
    $option = '';
    while($rezultat_lista_carti = mysql_fetch_assoc($lista_carti)) {
        $option .= '<option value = "'.$rezultat_lista_carti['titlu'].'">'.$rezultat_lista_carti['titlu'].'</option>';
    }
?>

<form method="post" class="formular" action="utilizator.php">
    <select name="titlu_carte"> 
        <?php echo $option; ?>
    </select>

    <input type="submit" name="submit2" value="Selecteaza Carte" />
</form>

<?php
    $titlu_carte = $_POST['titlu_carte'];
    $submit2 = $_POST['submit2'];
    $nume = $_SESSION['login'];

    if($submit2) {
        if($titlu_carte==null) { echo "<p class='eroare'>Selectati o carte din lista!</p>"; }
        else {
            $cautare2 = mysql_query("UPDATE `utilizatori` SET `cartea_favorita`=$titlu_carte WHERE `nume`=$nume");
            echo "<p class='succes'>Carte selectata cu success!</p>";
        }

    }
?>
```

Comment: verify in your html source, that `$option` variable under `select` has values

Comment: The drop-down list displays correctly.

Comment: `$titlu_carte` used in mysql_query needs to be wrapped in single quotes, if value is string

Comment: What do you mean by "does not add anything in the database"? You're aware of, that an UPDATE will just "update" and not "add" anything?

Comment: @kamalpal, that was the problem, thanks! :) I new it must be something little like that.

Comment: Welcome :), and stop using mysql_* functions, these are depreciated and will be removed in future. try [PDO] (http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php) instead

Comment: @DanielSarmas Please check my code. thanks

Answer (score 2):

Your problem is in your query. You forgot to add apostrophes on the variables in your query, so SQL wouldn't recognize it as a string, but as a column name which probably doesn't exists.

```
$cautare2 = mysql_query("UPDATE `utilizatori` SET `cartea_favorita` = '$titlu_carte' WHERE `nume` = '$nume'");
```

Since your variable `$titlu_carte` is coming from a `$_POST`, you should escape it to prevent problems when adding data to your db table.

So change this row:

```
$titlu_carte = $_POST['titlu_carte'];
```

into this:

```
$titlu_carte = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['titlu_carte']);
```

It will save you from future problems, and add a layer of protection against SQL Injection.